# Limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$ question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that all its restrictions on *lines through origin* have the same limit $L$ in $(0,0)$, is it necessary that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=L$$ ?

My guess is that it is necessary since every element of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$ which converges to $(0,0)$ lies on some line through origin, but I have no idea how to prove it nor do i know that it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

No. Take$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }y=x^2\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ doesn't exist, but the limit along any straight line passing through $(0,0)$ exists and it is equal to $0$.